# React not importing file. Console shows no errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to practice api but I'm stuck trying to import the recipe template. The form shows but nothing else. The console also shows no errors. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the App.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Recipe from "./Recipe.js";

function App() {
 
  let [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);

 
  useEffect(() => {
    getRecipes();
  }, []);


  const getRecipes = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      `///url///`
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    setRecipes = data.hits;
    console.log(data.hits);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form className="search-form">
        <input type="text" className="search-bar" />
        <button type="submit" className="search-button">
          Search
        </button>
      </form>
      {recipes.map(recipe => (
        <Recipe />
       
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is Recipe.js

```
const Recipe = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Calories</p>
     
    </div>
  );
};

export default Recipe;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not updating the recipes state inside the `getRecipes` function correctly. You should call the `setRecipes` state updater function with the new state.

```
setRecipes = data.hits;
```

should be

```
setRecipes(data.hits)
```

Comment: Thank you !! That was it